# Solr - how to return most frequent terms of a query

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

While performing a query `name:*b* AND country:China` (name contains 'b'), I want solr to return number of people (from China) with each different term

```
Documents(name are whitespace delimiter toknized):
[ 
{name: 'sponge bob'},
{name: 'billy chen'},
{name: 'abie white'}
]
```

Result expectd

```
[
{term: 'bob', matches: 100},
{term: 'billy', matches: 90},
{term: 'abie', matches: 80}
]
```

**Attemp: facet search**

I try query like `q=name:*b*+%3AAND+%3Acountry:China&facet=on&facet.field=name`

Result includes unrelated terms as

```
[sponge,1, bob, 1, ...]
```

How could I get ride of unrelated terms like `sponge`

Comment: Why does abie score lower than billy despite being shorter? Your query doesn't imply you're interested in starting with a b?

Comment: @Yann matches is not score, but how many pepole that named 'abie'

Comment: Just doing a search on the name, and facetting on name doesn't do what you want?

Comment: @Yann I'v update the question to make it clear

Comment: Got it - it should work if you create another field, with the same content as the name, but without the tokenization (just store it as a string). Then use this new field as your facetting field.

Comment: @Yann But I want to count the term not the field value

Comment: I see. Then... I'm not sure how to do that either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I modify the facet search implementation based on this patch `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1387` and build myself a brand new solr war

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your use case correctly, but the [TermsComponent](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent) may fit your needs.

It "provides access to the indexed terms in a field and the number of documents that match each term" (from the docs).

After configuring the component in your solrconfig.xml the query should look like this:

```
terms=true&terms.fl=name&terms.regex=.*b.*
```

Comment: TermsComponent can not return term frequence of a particular query, I think

Comment: Sorry for the unclear query, I've updated my querie.

Comment: You're right, but neither does faceting. Both return the document frequency, i.e. the number of documents containing the term. See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent#Specifying_Lower_Bound for a example response of the TermsComponent. Unless you have documents containing "peter peter" or something, this shouldn't bother you, I believe.

Comment: Actually  `facet.prefix` can filter terms starts with the prefix, but I am looking for `facet.regex` or `facet.contains`

Comment: But the TermsComponent is capable of this: terms.regex=.*b.*, see the query in my answer.

Comment: look at the updated query `name:*b* AND country:China` I cannot perform `country:China` with terms component